# Can't import langchain modules: Import "langchain.indexes" could not be resolved

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, langchain

while I was following the instructions of a tutorial on youtube, I noticed that I get an Error when trying to import the langchain modules altough I installed langchain.

My versions are:
Langchain version: 0.0.336
Python version: 3.10.12
OpenAI version: 1.3.0
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Here is my code where I get the error:

```
import os
import sys

import constants
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.llms import OpenAi

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY

query = sys.argv[1]

loader = TextLoader('data.txt')
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

print(index.query(query))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9etD.png)

I tried going back to older versions of langchain but it didn't work. 0.0.336 is the current version of langchain. I also tried to change to an older pydantic version as it was mentioned somewhere that it could solve the issue but I had no luck on this.

Any suggestions what could help?

Thanks in advance,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

I found [this reference](https://community.openai.com/t/attributeerror-module-openai-has-no-attribute-error/486676/12) which worked for me (looks like these are the new compatible versions).

```py
pip install langchain==0.0.343
pip install Openai==1.3.6
```